# How to know which number option is selected using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one html page where i have set of select menu like this give below.

```
   <label>Product Details</label>
      <select id="PD">
         <xsl:for-each select="PRODUCT_DETAILS">
           <option value="{DATA0}"><xsl:value-of select="DATA0"></xsl:value-of></option>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </select>

   <label>Price Details</label>
      <select id="PRD">
         <xsl:for-each select="PRICE_DETAILS">
           <option value="{DATA1}"><xsl:value-of select="DATA1"></xsl:value-of></option>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </select>
```

This select menu option is getting populated by some multi row xml as you can see. Now I if I select Product Details option number 2 then from price details ,option number 2 should get select auto.

I just wanted to know how to get which option number is get selected using jquery like say if i select if i selected option number 2 in Product Details it should give 2 as a result.

And based on this value how can i select option number 2 in price details using option number only using jquery.

Comment: `<select id="ProductDetails" onchange="this.form.PRICE_DETAILS.selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex" ...>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the index of the selected option

To get

```
var index = $('#selectid option:selected').index(); // it gives 0 based index
```

To set

```
$('#selectid option').eq(index).prop('selected', true)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SW2p3/)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
```

> The selectedIndex property sets or returns the index of the selected option in a drop-down list.
>
> The index starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example:

**In HTML:**

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
    <option value="4">Dr</option>
    <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>
```

**In JS:**

```
$( "#myselect option:selected" ).index();
```

Read about [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) here. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Antindexer/qnjb4/)**.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$( "#myselect option:selected" ).val();`?

Comment: @Phoenix Please Check my question , i know this thing. I want selected  option number by using jquery not the value and text of option selected. Like out of 5 option if i select 3rd then it should give 3rd and same option i want to auto select in other select menu.

Comment: @tewathia Right sorry I am in hurry little bit :)

Comment: @vishal_g—if you select the third option then the selected index will be 2. Option indexes are zero based.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myselect').get(0).selectedIndex;
```